# IOS Never removes event handler no matter what

Tags: javascript, ios, touchstart

I must be doing it wrong because even though it works on IE9+, Edge, ff, chrome, and android it doesn't work on IOS. This code, on IOS, will just keep on a runnin'. Is there a way to fix this?

```
function handleeeee() {
    alert("HANDL-O");
    document.body.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleeeee);
}
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", handleeeee, { once: true });
```

Comment: There are workarounds of course, a straightforward one is to use a variable.

Comment: var handleeeeeeeeee = function() {}? I get the same thing.

Comment: No, you use a separate variable to track whether the handler should run. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3cudjnp9/

Comment: Yeah but I shouldn't have to hack it like that. But since doing it the right way doesn't work all I am left with is hacks. I am very confused why removeEventListener doesn't work. I can call removeEventListener immediately after addEventListener and it will still call handleeeee.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the iOS version of Safari? According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions/safarieventtarget/1635368-removeeventlistener) the parameters need to match exactly. They don't in the code in your question. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Yep, that was it. The third parameter. Thanks.